# does ADT(eclipse) supports apklib or aar now, upto ADT v23.04?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, aar, apklib

Almost no one had successful import a Apklib(aar) refenerence in ADT.
Here is a [issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59183#makechanges), but no answer. In issues, this is a [solution](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) works but ugly.

Being a fan of ADT, i do not wanna use Android Studio.
is there some way to use Apklib(aar) in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

tried for sevearl weeks, i turned to idea with gradle.
as far as i kown, apklib is supported, while aar is not full supported. 
Here is one way to use AAR.

just unpackage the aar into a folder, then import into eclipse as a library project. do not forget to add the classes.jar into build path.
then add a library project dependency to you own project.

it works.